# generate cronschedule for two cronjobs which gets executed alternatively

Tags: cron, kubernetes-cronjob

i want to to write a script to create a cronschedule so that  ,
when the script runs, it should reada cron schedule provided as input and split the times half half between the two cron scheules , so that if the developer schedules a cronjob to run every hour (e.g. 1 o'clock, 2 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 4 o'clock, etc) the script should make a schedule for where the schedule is set for every 2 hours (in this example 1 o'clock, 3' o'clock, etc ....) and another cronjob for where the schedule is also every 2 hours, but the remaining timings (so here 2 o'clock, 4 o'clock, etc)

is there any existing function/code to implement this ?